# How can I add a JavaFX 2.0 class to an existing Maven project?

Tags: maven, javafx

I have a Maven project that just displays a graph on the xy axis. I want to change that graph to a Javafx 2.0 linechart to display the same data. I tried using the FEST-javafx-maven plugin, but I still cannot compile the code; the compiler cannot find all of the javafx.xxx imports.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

*Update (Oct 6 2015)*

Modern JavaFX versions (shipped with Oracle Java 8+) do not require any additional class path to use JavaFX.  The JavaFX runtime is on the default classpath Java uses for compilation and execution.  This means that a plain maven pom.xml file, with no additional dependencies, will build a JavaFX application.

However, if you wish to use additional packaging features for your application, such as the ability to deploy it as a [self-contained application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html), then I advise using the (third party) [JavaFX Maven plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin).

*Previous Answer*

The following information in this answer is now mostly old and outdated.

The link to the fest maven plugin I found (http://fest.easytesting.org/javafx/maven/) is to a tool for building JavaFX 1.x script projects, which is a completely different and incompatible beast to JavaFX 2.0 - I'm not sure if there is an updated version of the fest maven plugin which supports JavaFX 2.0.

There is currently no official support for Maven from Oracle, nor a version of JavaFX 2.0 in a publicly hosted Maven repository.

However, I have successfully built JavaFX 2.0 projects using maven in the past by using a system scoped dependency on the jfxrt.jar and (optionally) invoking the JavaFX ant tasks from maven.

If you are embedding your graph in an existing Swing application via a JFXPanel, then you don't need to use the JavaFX ant tasks.  Add jfxrt.jar from the JavaFX runtime as a system dependency OR manually install it into your maven repository to use a non-system scoped dependency.

An example of the command to manually install the required JavaFX 2.0 runtime jar is:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile="C:\Program Files\Oracle\JavaFX 2.1.0 SDK\rt\lib\jfxrt.jar" -DgroupId=com.oracle.javafx -DartifactId=javafx -Dversion=2.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

After running the above command, add the dependency to the jfxrt.jar file to your maven pom and your project compilation should resolve all JavaFX API references:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle.javafx</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you extend the JavaFX Application class and you want your application packaged for deployment via webstart, browser embedding or as a JavaFX installation aware clickable jar, then you should adapt your pom.xml file to execute the relevant JavaFX 2.0 ant tasks - http://code.google.com/p/willow-browser/source/browse/pom.xml demonstrates such an adaption.

These threads discuss JavaFX 2.0 maven support and provide further background info and samples:

- https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9970002
- http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2011-December/000076.html

Comment: Thanks for all of your help sofar.

Comment: What I am really trying to do is replace an existing JPanel that has a graph, with a JFX2.0 linechart. I this doable without redrawing the entire JFrame etc?

Comment: Yes, just replace the JPanel with a JFXPanel, see here for documentation => http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html

Comment: For a sample of how to use the JFXPanel, Oracle has provided a SwingInterOp demo - you can try out the demo and download it's source code from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/samples/index.html.  The SwingInterOp demo places a JavaFX graph inside a panel in a Swing application, which seems to be exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and here is my solution:

If using Java 7u7 (javafx is integrated into jdk/jre):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javafx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

For previous versions of java:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javafx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${env.JAVAFX_HOME}\rt\lib\jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

And you have to set system variable JAVAFX_HOME to home dir of JavaFx.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the [JavaFX Maven plugin](https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin).  This takes care of adding javafx to the classpath as well as building JavaFX apps and creating Windows/Mac/Linux executables, as well as double-clickable JARs and JNLP files.

Answer (score 0):

Using JDK 1.7 you have to perform the following mvn goal.

```
  mvn com.zenjava:javafx-maven-plugin:2.0:fix-classpath
```

This command will change the classpath of your JRE and copy the jfxrt.jar to the JAVA_HOME\lib\ext directory.

Take an additional look here for further information: 
[JavaFX Maven Plugin](https://web.archive.org/web/20141004151313/http://zenjava.com/javafx/maven/fix-classpath.html)

Within your pom-file you have to add the following dependency configuration.

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>javafx</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfxrt</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <!-- <version>${javafx.min.version}</version> -->
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```