# javafx application in maven project

Tags: java, maven-3, javafx-2

I have a project with structure like this:

main-project
-libary-1
-library-2
-i-need-javafx-app-here

So, i need a JavaFX 2 application in my maven project, and it should use library-1 and library-2 with its dependencies. I can't find any maven archetypes for JavaFX 2 projects and i cand find any adequate information about how i can build JavaFX app by Maven 3. I don't need any deployment to web, it will only desktop app.

So, can anybody help with this problem?

UPD:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

    ...

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application`
exception is occured when i try to run application, which is builded by **pgras** way.

Comment: See [How can I add a JavaFX 2.0 class to an existing Maven project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916461/how-can-i-add-a-javafx-2-0-class-to-an-existing-maven-project/8918191)

Comment: Are you working on windows or on another OS ? I ask because I also had some difficulties to set this up and so far I have a working solution on Windows and still some problems on MacOS. I can give a longer explanation how I did it on windows...

Comment: BTW how do you try to run the  application ?

Comment: I working on windows. I try run it by two way: first is "java -jar myapp.jar", and second through Netbeans - i set up the main class in project properties and netbeans try to run it by maven run plugin. The result is equal.

Answer (score 5):

So I guess you already use Java 7, I d'ont know exactly what you need, for compiling you will need only the dependency to javafx, so in your pom for the javafx app:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <systemPath>${javafx.rt.jar}</systemPath>
        <scope>system</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And in your maven settings.xml add (and adapt path to your system):

```
<profile>
  <id>javafx</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <javafx.rt.jar>C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\JavaFX 2.0 SDK\rt\lib\jfxrt.jar</javafx.rt.jar>
    <ant.javafx.jar>C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\JavaFX 2.0 SDK\tools\ant-javafx.jar</ant.javafx.jar>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

It should be enough to compile and make jar file... If not tell me and I'll post more info...

Answer (score 2):

Thank you a lot, this link is helpful. So, now my pom looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>info.kosmonaffft</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-example</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>javafx-maven-example</name>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <excludeArtifactIds>junit,hamcrest-core</excludeArtifactIds>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <taskdef name="jfxjar" classname="com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.FXJar" classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath"/>
                                <jfxjar destfile="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}">
                                    <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/classes"/>
                                    <application name="${project.name}" mainClass="info.kosmonaffft.jfxexample.App"/>
                                    <resources>
                                    </resources>
                                </jfxjar>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.oracle.javafx</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ant-javafx</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0</version>
                        <scope>system</scope>
                        <systemPath>C:\Program Files\Oracle\JavaFX 2.1 SDK\tools\ant-javafx.jar</systemPath>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javafx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>C:\Program Files\Oracle\JavaFX 2.1 SDK\rt\lib\jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

So, it is possible to run application from command line "java -jar myapp.jar" now, but i have not tested how it will runs with dependencies.

Comment: there is a problem with dependencies - I got java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

Answer (score 0):

I add another answer because it's a long one, and it shows how I do to also generate a signed jar and a JNLP webstart file.

So first I create a certificate to be able to sign the jar (you'll be asked to enter some info, I used "superpass" for the passwords, look where it is used in pom) :

```
cd src/main/java
mkdir jnlp
cd jnlp
keytool -genkey -alias signFiles -keystore keystore.jks
```

And then I use this pom.xml (which has a parent pom but it doesn't contain anything related to javafx):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
     xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <artifactId>testfx</artifactId>
    <groupId>ch.pgras</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<groupId>ch.pgras</groupId>
<artifactId>hellofx</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>hellofx</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <systemPath>${javafx.rt.jar}</systemPath>
        <scope>system</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <taskdef name="jfxdeploy" classname="com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.DeployFXTask"
                                     classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath"/>

                            <taskdef name="jfxsignjar" classname="com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.FXSignJarTask"
                                     classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath"/>

                            <jfxdeploy width="800" height="600" outdir="${project.build.directory}/deploy"
                                       outfile="${project.build.finalName}">
                                <info title="${project.name}"/>
                                <application name="${project.name}" mainclass="webmap.WebMap"/>
                                <resources>
                                    <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}" includes="*.jar"/>
                                    <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/dependency"
                                             includes="*.jar"/>
                                </resources>
                                <platform javafx="2.0">
                                    <jvmarg value="-Xms64m"/>
                                    <jvmarg value="-Xmx256m"/>
                                </platform>
                            </jfxdeploy>
                            <jfxsignjar destdir="${project.build.directory}/deploy"
                                        keystore="${project.basedir}/src/main/java/jnlp/keystore.jks"
                                        storepass="superpass" alias="signFiles" keypass="superpass">
                                <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/deploy" includes="*.jar"/>
                            </jfxsignjar>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.oracle.javafx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ant-javafx</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0</version>
                    <systemPath>${ant.javafx.jar}</systemPath>
                    <scope>system</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

finally I run mvn install, and the result will be in target/deploy...

good luck :)

Comment: Thanks, but when i try to run through jnlp it runs, when i try to run it through maven run plugin or through "java -jar myapp.jar" ClassNotFoundException is still exist. I don't need jnlp, i need possibility to run application by second way, is it possible with JavaFX?

Comment: Not yet tested but this may help: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2373227&tstart=240

Comment: When I try this I get an icon in "JavaFX click for free update". If I click on "click to launch" I just get a newer version of JavaFX is required. I tried changing version 2.0 to 2.2 above. However I don't think the problem is the version of JavaFX / Java in my browser is out of date because I have almost been able to build it using the jfx maven plugin https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin but it fails when I try to access network resources even though it should have signed the application.